# Who is the guru/master for an astrology/prasangam in hinduism/puranas on earth

Tags: puranas, astrology, guru

Can someone give me a source of Guru in an Astrology 'Vaanasasthiram' in the starting of Hinduism/puranas on earth planet. And how did he become a master/guru of an astrology.

**Updated:**
How we can predicts the human whats going to be happened in future that's called astrology. Who is the first person identified and created to learn the astrology.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.. what is Vanasasthiram? "Who's a Guru in astrology?" only this portion is understandable to me..

Comment: Okay so u want to know who's the "creator" of astrology or who's the first person to have got that knowledge.

Comment: @AnuragSingh: Do you have any source??

Comment: I mean almost all Rishi Munis have told about astrology, like Jaimini Sutras, Vashishtha, and Narayan Rishi told a bit in Devi Puraan. But I did not see anyone say that I or some other person started Astrology. What I mean to say is that probably all Rishi  knew astrology, as almost all seem to know about astrology. However, I must check if there is really a description of founder of astrology. But cannot say right now.